# Desbordamiento de pila (stack overflow) en destructor de Singleton

Tags: c++, singleton

Al llamar al destructor de este 'singleton' que sirve de clase base

```
template<typename T>
class SingletonBase
{
    static T* ms_SingletonBase;

protected:
    SingletonBase()
    {
        std::cout << " SingletonBase constructor\n";
        assert(!ms_SingletonBase);
        int offset = (int)(T*)1 - (int)(SingletonBase<T>*)(T*)1;
        ms_SingletonBase = (T*)((int)this + offset);
    }
public:
    virtual ~SingletonBase()
    { 
        std::cout << " SingletonBase destructor\n";
        assert(ms_SingletonBase);
        if (ms_SingletonBase)
        {
            std::cout << " ms_SingletonBase != nullptr\n";
            delete ms_SingletonBase;
            ms_SingletonBase = 0;
        }
    }

    static T& get()
    {
        assert(ms_SingletonBase);
        return (*ms_SingletonBase);
    }

    static T* getSingletonPtr() { return (ms_SingletonBase); }
};

template<typename T> T* SingletonBase <T>::ms_SingletonBase = 0;
```

se produce un 'desbordamiento de pila' (stack overflow) en dicho destructor. Entiendo que el llamar a `delete` dentro del destructor, invoca al mismo destructor, que vuelve a llamar a `delete` y así sucesivamente hasta que se desborda, pero entonces ¿cómo hago para borrar el puntero `ms_SingletonBase` (que el destructor me dice que no es `nullptr`) y que no haya fugas de memoria?

Comment: El código del destructor es la perfecta receta para el desastre. Haces que el puntero apunte a un espacio de memoria que no le corresponde haciendo una transformación de dicho espacio de memoria de manera no segura, sin invocar constructores y sin reservar memoria. Un `SingletonBase` de tipos fundamentales podría funcionar de casualidad, pero sobre una clase compleja como `std::string` destruirá el tejido del espacio-tiempo o simplemente hará fallar tu programa.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster esperemos que lo segundo ;).

Comment: No tientes a la suerte ¡quema ese código con fuego!

Comment: Y si, como dice Eferion, la parte del `if(ms_SingletonBase)...` hasta el final del destructor no sirve para nada ¿cómo puede pasar esa asignación insegura de memoria?.. pregunto  humildemente por supuesto :)

Comment: Esa "*asignación insegura de memoria*" pasa porque no has usado ninguna de las herramientas que [tag:c++] ofrece para evitar que pase.

Comment: Si usas tipos construibles por defecto, valora [usar variables plantilla como singleton](https://wandbox.org/permlink/1LYZLy4DUR7Rd3Cd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El desbordamiento lo tienes porque estás forzando un doble borrado. Dado que la clase `POO` hereda de `SingletonBase`, al destruir `POO` se invoca el destructor de `SingletonBase` que a su vez intenta borrar `POO`... y vuelta a empezar.

Para garantizar que los objetos se destruyen al finalizar la aplicación puedes hacer lo siguiente:

```
template<typename T>
class SingletonBase
{
    static T& get()
    {
       static T instance;
       return instance;
    }
}
```

Al instanciar `T` de forma estática, a la finalización de la aplicación se invocará el destructor de `T` de forma totalmente transparente para ti.

Si, en cambio quieres manejar manualmente la vida de los *singleton*, tienes que hacerlo a través de un **método estático**:

```
template<typename T>
class SingletonBase
{
    static void DeleteSingleton()
    {
        std::cout << " SingletonBase destructor\n";
        assert(ms_SingletonBase);
        if (ms_SingletonBase)
        {
            std::cout << " ms_SingletonBase != nullptr\n";
            delete ms_SingletonBase;
            ms_SingletonBase = 0;
        }  
    }
}
```

Por cierto, nota que el `assert` te arrojará un error en tiempo de compilación si `ms_SingletonBase` apunta a *null*, luego el `if` que le sigue es totalmente innecesario.

Por si no fuera suficiente, el siguiente código es totalmente seguro:

```
T* ptr = 0;
delete ptr;
delete ptr;
delete ptr;
// ...
```

Es decir, es seguro borrar un puntero que apunta a 0, luego el `if`, como ves, no sirve absolutamente para nada.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. La función `static void DeleteSingleton()`es algo que difícilmente se me hubiera ocurrido.

Comment: ¿Quién querría heredar de `SingletonBase`? ¿Estás hablando de CRTP? O_o

Comment: @¿Y eliminar `delete ms_SingletonBase` y dejar solo `ms_SingletonBase = 0` en el destructor sería suficiente para evitar la fuga hipotética fuga de memoria?

Comment: @Battyhal funcionaría pero no tendría sentido. Lo normal es que no borres el singleton de forma manual

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster Heredar de singleton te puede servir para que los objetos se eliminen en un orden determinado (por necesidades varias o dependencias)

Comment: ¿Pero qué sentido tiene `MiClase : SingletonBase<MiClase>`? (CRTP) ¿O `Engendro : SingletonBase<float>`? ¿O `Abominación : Engendro, MiClase, SingletonBase<SingletonBase<int>>`?

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster ya bueno, el lenguaje en ese aspecto no te limita... el que no tenga sentido común que apechugue con las consecuencias :)

Comment: Las interfaces más bellas son aquellas que evitan (o hacen difícil) que puedas hacer disparates con ellas.

Comment: @PaperBirdMaster con casi cualquier función de `<algorithm>` puedes hacer aberraciones... ¿son por ello menos útiles o menos bellas?

Comment: Las aberraciones que puedes hacer con las funciones de `<algorithm>` están muy limitadas y en su mayoría pasan por las burradas que haga el predicado. No son perfectas, pero tienen mejor diseño (y belleza) que este singleton.